# why might "Adjusts font automatically" not be working?

Tags: ios, fonts, system, dynamic-type-feature

Big legacy code base. I started using storyboards. Great! Now I check "Adjusts font automatically" for a UILabel. I run the app. I play with the system font size. Changes show in Messages but not in App. Not even if I restart. Using the default "system" font, as well as trying with a custom font.
Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't **use the [text styles](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#text-size)** in your `UILabel`, you won't be able to change the text sizes even if you tick the `Automatically Adjusts Fonts` in the Xcode Interface Builder.

Just change the font of your label with a specific text style and you'll see immediately the difference:

- **Xcode 10** ⟹ use the `Accessibility Inspector` tool to modify rapidly the text size inside its `settings` section.
- **Xcode 11** ⟹ use the `Environment overrides` tool located in the `Debug Area` panel to modify rapidly the text size *(only visible after build and run)*.

Many useful information about the `Dynamic Type` implementation are available in this [detailed WWDC video summary](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html) if need be.